# Find ipv4 address on Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

I'm currently trying to figure out how to make a custom domain with Heroku using Google Domains.

In Google Domains it gives me the "Custom resource records" option and I'm trying to figure out what to add in the IPv4 address field. It will only let me add numbers, and not sure how to find my IPv4 address for my current Heroku domain name. Any help or places to look?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should follow Heroku's guide on adding a custom domain: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Heroku does not officially support A records, and though it may be possible to find your heroku app's IP address, the address can (and probably will) change. Instead, Heroku recommends setting a CNAME on a subdomain to `[your-app-id].herokuapp.com`.

Comment: So it's not possible to set your domain e.g "myApp.dev" to the heroku DNS e.g `made-up-string.herokudns.com`? If so this is a shame... will probably have to use Route 53 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow just figured it out. Didn't realize there was an option for CNAME. Simply change the type to CNAME and then enter your Heroku domain.

[image]